# Make Grid rows visible based on user's choice (or other alternative to display different UI component upon choice)

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I am designing a WPF UserControl, which needs to display different components based on user's choice. But since this UserControl is still relatively simple, I decided to only have one View (this UserControl) and one ViewModel. So basically what I have is one combobox which has options of enum values(at least three options) to indicate which specific part the user wants to see. For the individual components, what I designed now is, I have a `Grid` with multiple `GridRow`. And only the rows representing the user's choice data would have the visibility as `Visible` . Other rows/views have visibility as `Collapsed`. But there are two problems:

1. In one grid row, I have one `ScrollViewer`. As far as I
   have learned, I can't set the height of the GridRow where the
   `ScrollViewer` resides in as `Auto`. Because the scroll bar will
   never work with `Auto`(since the actual height is large enough to display all so no need to have a scroll bar). However, if I don't set the height as
   `Auto`, the height would not become zero(so this row will not be
   displayed) when I set the visibility of this row as `Collapsed`. For
   example, if I set the grid row height as `*` and then the visibility
   of the `ScrollViewer` as `Collapsed`, the `ScrollViewer` will not be
   displayed but there is still an empty space corresponding to one
   star's height.
2. As I mentioned, I have at least 3 options/different views. So a binding from a bool property to visibility is not enough. I guess I can make a dedicate converter, but it doesn't feel about generic enough.

Can anybody tell me, how I can achieve my goal, i.e., to display different UI parts with one UserControl(all binding to the the same ViewModel) based on user's choice?

Comment: We had a [similar question](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/12391628#12391628) over @[`WPF`](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf) recently (scroll down to read Reed Copsey's summary or up to find out more about the specific case, the link points to the XAML that made it work), feel free to pop up if you don't get a response or have more issues (this is not really `MVVM`, but if you want to do it using the pattern, i reckon you might want to use multiple `DataTemplates` and `DataTypes` as shown [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/))...

Comment: @StefanDenchev thanks for your comment. I guess it would solve my second problem (even though it requires some twisting of UI and VM, but not big deal). But it doesn't solve the first one: the dilemma of using Auto to make it disappear when the visibility is collapsed, and not using Auto since ScrollViewer would not work

Comment: @StefanDenchev And regarding to using `DaTaTemplate`, I don't see how I can use it in my case: the different views and the data behind them are quite different. For example, in one view I have one `ObservableCollection` based on which I want to draw multiple graphs. And in another one I want to display a `DataGrid` to display some statistics. So in the ViewModel I expose two properties, one `ObservableCollection` of `ObjectTypeA`, and one `List` of `ObjectTypeB`. I don't see how I use `DataTemplate` for configure the visibility of these different views.

Comment: I have used the above pattern in much more complex scenarios, though it might not be feasible in this one, i haven't really gone in depth... Basically you use an itemscontrol and bind the content property to the datatype which is chosen - let's call it `CurrentDT`, and you manipulate that (i.e change it based on the user's choice), then the appropriate datatemplate is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just put each 'view' into its own `Grid` and create an `EnumToVisibilityConverter` to alternate their `Visibility`:

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Converters:EnumToVisibilityConverter x:Key="EnumToVisibilityConverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid Name="View1" Visibility="{Binding EnumInstance, Converter={StaticResource 
        EnumToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=Option1">
        ...
    </Grid>
    <Grid Name="View2" Visibility="{Binding EnumInstance, Converter={StaticResource 
        EnumToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=Option2">
        ...
    </Grid>
    <Grid Name="View3" Visibility="{Binding EnumInstance, Converter={StaticResource 
        EnumToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=Option3">
        ...
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Converter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(Enum), typeof(Visibility))]
public class EnumToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || parameter == null) return false;
        string enumValue = value.ToString();
        string targetValue = parameter.ToString();
        return enumValue.Equals(targetValue, 
            StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ? Visibility.Visible : 
            Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

Of course, this assumes that you know how to add a `Converter` with XML namespace into your XAML and that your `enum` property is named `EnumIntance` and your `enum` values are named `Option1`, `Option2` and `Option3`.

> I haven't been able to test this, so let me know if there are any problems with it

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll update the result as soon as I test it

Comment: I think this solution works since it solves my problem of not able to use `Auto` as height since it doesn't work with `ScrollViewer`. Many thanks!